# Querydsl InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException when using CaseBuilder

Tags: java, spring, querydsl

## Domain

```
public class X {
    private AC ac;
}

public class AC {
    private AP ap;
}

public class AP {
    private List<AC> acs;
    private BD bd;
}

public class BD {
    private List<AP> aps;
    private List<BD> childBds;
    private BD parentBD;
}
```

Bd entries in the Database are either Parents with childBds or childBds With a parent and a number of APs. Parent Bds are never directly linked to Aps, only to their childBds.

## Query

```
public Predicate createPredicate(Integer bdId) {
    QX qX = new QX("x");
    BooleanExpression expression = // Some predicate which isn't causing issues
    QAp qAp = new QAp(qX.a.ap.getMetaData(), PathInits.DIRECT);
    QBd qChildBd = new QBd(qAp.bd().getMetaData(), PathInits.DIRECT);
    QBd qParentBd = new QBd(qChildBd.parentBd().getMetaData(), PathInits.DIRECT);
    BooleanExpression childOrParentBd = new CaseBuilder().
        when(qParentBd.id.eq(bdId).and(qParentBd.childBds.size.gt(0))).
            then((Predicate) qParentBd.id.eq(bdId)).
        otherwize(qChildBd.id.eq(bdId));
    return expression.and(childOrParentBd);
}
```

The goal of this predicate is to be used in a query's where clause, in order to retrieve all X for a which are linked to the specific bdId. The Id's are unique but I have no way of knowing if the bdId belongs to a Bd with children or a Bd with a parent.

To check if the bdId belongs to a parentBd I check if the corresponding Bd has childBds. If this is the case the predicate used in the expression needs to be qParentBd.id.eq(bdId). If this is not the case it needs to be qChildBd.id.eq(bdId).

I might be wrong but all of this seems correct to me. However when the query is executed I get an Exception:

`InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: case near line 3, column 3850`

At this line I and position I have the case statement:

`case when (x.ac.ap.bd.parent.id = ?1 and size(x.ac.ap.bd.parentBd.childBds) > ?94) then (x.ac.ap.bd.parentBd.id = ?1) else (x.ac.ap.bd.id = ?1) end`

## What have I tried

1. I looked at the documentation for [InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException.html). Judging by the unable to compile query I asume I'm using the `case when then end` statement incorrectly.
2. I found this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384454/using-an-in-predicate-with-case-statements-in-the-where-clause-for-sql-server) and tried to add the `... .otherwize(qChild.id.eq(BdId).eq(true))` This resulted in a `QueryException: Could not determine data type for searched case statement`Exception. I decided to look into the other solutions provided by the post first.
3. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

## Lesson learned: Keep it simple

I changed the `case when then end` clause for a simple `x OR y` clause which seems to have fixed this specific issue.

```
public Predicate createPredicate(Integer bdId) {
    QX qX = new QX("x");
    BooleanExpression expression = // Some predicate which isn't causing issues
    QAp qAp = new QAp(qX.a.ap.getMetaData(), PathInits.DIRECT);
    QBd qChildBd = new QBd(qAp.bd().getMetaData(), PathInits.DIRECT);
    QBd qParentBd = new QBd(qChildBd.parentBd().getMetaData(), PathInits.DIRECT);
    BooleanExpression childOrParentBd = bovenBeleidsDoelstelling.id.eq(beleidsDoelstellingId)
        .or(beleidsDoelstelling.id.eq(beleidsDoelstellingId));
    return expression.and(childOrParentBd);
}
```

Since the bdId is unique it should be enough to check the two possible QueryDsl Paths:

1. `x.ac.ap.bd.parentBd.id.eq(bdId)`
2. `x.ac.ap.bd.id.ed(bdId)`

If either of the two is found it will only return `x` results for this specific bdId.

## IMPORTANT

This does not explain why I was getting the errors I was getting. If someone would elaborate on that, it would be greatly appreciated.